# Construct an estimator for the asymptotic variance of the MLE and and its asymptotic distribution

Tags: regression, distributions, self-study, variance, maximum-likelihood

[image]

This is a question I have come across while learning about statistical inference and data analysis.

I think I have been able to solve question (a) and (b) already.
My solutions are:

$$
\hat{p}_{MLE} = \frac{n}{n + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i} = \frac{1}{1+\bar{x}_n}
$$

$$
\sqrt{n}(\hat{p}_{MLE} - p) \rightarrow N(0,\frac{1}{I_n(p)})
$$
with
$$
I_n(p) = \frac{1}{p^2(1-p)}
$$

However, I have no clue how to solve questions (c) and (d).
Can someone help me with this please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We will have to be generous in interpreting "asymptotic variance" (which obviously is *zero*) as $p^2(1-p)/n.$ Abstractly, then, suppose you are given a function like $p\to p^2(1-p)/n$ for a fixed $n.$  How would you estimate this quantity from a sample of size $n$?

Comment: @whuber Can we estimate this by filling in $\hat{p}_{MLE}$ into p?

Comment: That's the usual way.  After all, the MLE of any (reasonable) function of a parameter is the function of its MLE.

Comment: @whuber ok so if we fill that in, we get an estimator for the asymptotic variance of the MLE. Thanks you for that. However, I don't know how I should continue to find its asymptotic distribution. Do you also have any ideas for that?

Comment: The delta method could be a useful device to continue.

Comment: @Christoph Or, almost equivalently, re-working the Fisher Information matrix in terms of the parameter $p^2(1-p)/n$ would do it.